# PJSIP for Android (2019)

Tags: android-studio, pjsip

Is there a CMake version of the PJSIP library, or we should say goodbye to PJSIP for Android?

I've built the project using [this](https://github.com/halex2005/pjproject) helper and got the .so files, but this helper is a little old, besides it's output is not suitable for Android Studio.

- I've swum in [PJSIP](https://www.pjsip.org) website, but they provide no useful explanation among their vast nested documentation-called content.
- I've tries to send a message to "benny@prijono.org", but this email address does not exist.
- I've tried to subscribe to "[lists.pjsip.org](https://lists.pjsip.org)", but as you can guess, no help.
- I've tried to reach [PJSIP developers](https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/graphs/contributors) through "github", but none of them has provided a way to contact them.
- I've also read the answers for similar questions on Stackoverflow, but no CMake file.

Should I be an expert on C programming to use this library, or I haven't spent enough time searching the Internet for a clear answer?

If you are using "pjproject v2.8" in an Android application, please share your knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have tried https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android and got stuck? Please update your question with where in the steps you got stuck.

Comment: @PerryIsmangil I already mentioned in the first line buddy. CMake version of the project. Right now I must use command line to build the parts and in the end compile them together and find some .so files as the result. Although they didn't provide clear information about building for different needs, (for example no video and G729 codec). Besides, nowadays Android Studio builds libraries by CMake file.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a lot of time trying to build this library for Android.
I've been able to build PJSUA2 for `arm64-v8a` and `armeabi-v7a` architectures, but it fails with errors for `x86_64` and `x86`.

I updated the repository with the latest release (2.9) in hope for the bug to be fixed. But the new version doesn't even build the *.a files.

```
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/cstddef:50:9: error: no member named
      'ptrdiff_t' in the global namespace
using ::ptrdiff_t;
      ~~^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/cstddef:51:9: error: no member named
      'size_t' in the global namespace
using ::size_t;
      ~~^
In file included from ../../yuv/source/compare.cc:14:
In file included from /home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/math.h:309:
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:763:22: error: unknown type
      name 'size_t'
template <class _Tp, size_t _Np> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_array<_Tp[_Np]>
                     ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1282:32: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'size_t'; did you mean 'sizeof'?
    : public integral_constant<size_t, 0> {};
                               ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1282:38: error: expected
      expression
    : public integral_constant<size_t, 0> {};
                                     ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1282:43: error: expected
      class name
    : public integral_constant<size_t, 0> {};
                                          ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1284:32: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'size_t'; did you mean 'sizeof'?
    : public integral_constant<size_t, rank<_Tp>::value + 1> {};
                               ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1284:38: error: expected
      expression
    : public integral_constant<size_t, rank<_Tp>::value + 1> {};
                                     ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1284:49: error: expected
      class name
    : public integral_constant<size_t, rank<_Tp>::value + 1> {};
                                                ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1285:22: error: unknown
      type name 'size_t'
template <class _Tp, size_t _Np> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS rank<_Tp[_Np]>
                     ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1286:32: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'size_t'; did you mean 'sizeof'?
    : public integral_constant<size_t, rank<_Tp>::value + 1> {};
                               ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1286:38: error: expected
      expression
    : public integral_constant<size_t, rank<_Tp>::value + 1> {};
                                     ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1286:49: error: expected
      class name
    : public integral_constant<size_t, rank<_Tp>::value + 1> {};
                                                ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1297:32: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'size_t'; did you mean 'sizeof'?
    : public integral_constant<size_t, 0> {};
                               ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1297:38: error: expected
      expression
    : public integral_constant<size_t, 0> {};
                                     ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1297:43: error: expected
      class name
    : public integral_constant<size_t, 0> {};
                                          ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1299:32: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'size_t'; did you mean 'sizeof'?
    : public integral_constant<size_t, 0> {};
                               ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1299:38: error: expected
      expression
    : public integral_constant<size_t, 0> {};
                                     ^
/home/adminz/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/type_traits:1299:43: error: expected
      class name
    : public integral_constant<size_t, 0> {};
                                          ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

Before I update my svn repo with the release version, errors where as follows:

```
/home/adminz/android/pjsip/third_party/lib/libwebrtc-x86_64-pc-linux-android.a(aec_core.o):aec_core.c:function WebRtcAec_CreateAec: error: undefined reference to 'WebRtc_GetCPUInfo'
/home/adminz/android/pjsip/third_party/lib/libwebrtc-x86_64-pc-linux-android.a(aec_core.o):aec_core.c:function WebRtcAec_CreateAec: error: undefined reference to 'WebRtcAec_InitAec_SSE2'
/home/adminz/android/pjsip/third_party/lib/libwebrtc-x86_64-pc-linux-android.a(aec_rdft.o):aec_rdft.c:function aec_rdft_init: error: undefined reference to 'WebRtc_GetCPUInfo'
/home/adminz/android/pjsip/third_party/lib/libwebrtc-x86_64-pc-linux-android.a(aec_rdft.o):aec_rdft.c:function aec_rdft_init: error: undefined reference to 'aec_rdft_init_sse2'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Makefile:165: recipe for target 'android/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/libpjsua2.so' failed
```

Should we also try to fix the library inner errors?
My final conclusion is that PjProject is a contraption (for some platforms) and it's developers don't even test the release version much enough and they use the users as their test case. I'm so frustrated with pjsip. So many features as some no-useful packages.